# The verb "dispute" followed by the gerund

Tags: gerunds

They disputed stealing the merchandise.

Do you think the sentence correct? Or should it be "They disputed over stealing the merchandise."?

What does it mean?

> 1. They were rejecting the accusation of their stealing the
>    merchandise.
> 2. They were in disagreement about whether it was the right think to
>    do that is to steal the merchandise.
> 3. They were in disagreement about whether they should steal the
>    merchandise later.

Comment: What is the source of the sentence, please

Comment: and please reference your favour dictionary definitions of the word "dispute".

Answer (score 1):

> Q1 They disputed stealing the merchandise.
> Q2 They disputed over stealing the merchandise.

Dispute can be transitive or intransitive.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dispute

> dispute
> verb [ I or T ]
> UK  /dɪˈspjuːt/ US  /dɪˈspjuːt/

> C2
> to disagree with something that someone says:
> Few would dispute his status as the finest artist of the period.

Both examples above are hence grammatical, but they have different meanings.

Q1 has a meaning similar to (1) below.

Q2 has a meaning closer to (3); (2) stresses on 'whether it was *the right thing*' and is hence slightly different from (3), which is on *whether they should* steal.

> They were rejecting the accusation of their stealing the merchandise.

> They were in disagreement about whether it was the right [thing] to do that is to steal the merchandise.

> They were in disagreement about whether they should steal the merchandise later.